# How massive is the black hole in "World Enough and Time/The Doctor Falls"?

Tags: doctor-who, physics

You might be thinking that we cannot possibly know, because there's nothing on screen about it.  But I think that this is one of those mind-bending puzzles where we seemingly have no information at all but actually we can deduce enough to make some pretty shrewd estimates.

- We saw two mission time clocks, giving the relative time rates on two decks of the ship.
- We saw a city with skyscrapers, whose sizes we can estimate from the number of floors.
- We saw just after the opening titles the approximate height of a deck relative to the skyscrapers.
- We know the deck numbers.
- We saw no appreciable tidal effects.

Let's assume general relativity as in the real universe (given than the writers made a plot point out of it), normal sized humans and time lords, and Terran standard days and hours (given the whole Mondas being a twin of Earth thing).  Let's also assume common Terran sizes of skyscrapers, if we cannot see all of the windows of any one in order to count them.  And let's assume that what we saw of the hospital applies generally: not more than one row of windows per floor.

It seems that we know two points and the distance between them, and the relative rates of time dilation, giving us a gradient; and we also know that tidal effects are weak.  We even know that the axis of the ship is perpendicular to the axis of rotation of the black hole, because its accretion disc was shown on screen as observed from the ship.

The ship is clearly under thrust, *towards* the black hole, and from the alignment of the decks shown just after the opening titles it is implied that artificial gravity is designed to be a product of that thrust.  Let's assume a thrust of 1G, which is consistent with what appears on screen.

Can we deduce the mass of the black hole from any or all of this?  Or at least bounds upon that mass?  If so, what is it?  If not, what information do we lack?

Comment: I recall a line from the janitor on the bridge saying something to the effect that they could not get away and were basically stuck between their trust and the pull of the black hole.

Comment: The people over at Physics.SE would be able to answer this. You might want to ask over there.

Comment: The physics shown in the show is at great variance with real physics. As such, your question is off-topic on this stack if you want a proper explanation.

Comment: Didn't they say the ship is 400 miles long and 100 miles wide? Or am I remembering something else?

Comment: J Doe you need to familiarize yourself with Physics's policy, which specifically excludes _physics of fictional universes_.  Valorum, you need to refresh your memory of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7367/21871 .  This is a question about a science fictional object, based upon what is seen on screen and some fairly reasonable assumptions about what unstated physics we can fill in, that are indeed based upon actual plot points.  We are on the right site.

Comment: And amflare, given that we _see_ the drives in the opening shot and which direction they are pointing, and have that backed up by which end of the ship is running faster than the other, let's go with what we outright see on screen rather than what you recall of the dialogue.

Comment: @JdeBP - I'm well aware of the policy. Did you read down as far as the conclusion; "*Questions which are explicitly asking for an out-of-universe explanation of the science from a work of science fiction or fantasy should be off-topic.*"

Comment: @JdeBP - Don't forget to include an @ if you want to ping someone. I only saw your comment because my name jumped out at me.

Comment: You are clearly grossly mis-applying it, then.  This question does not ask for out-of-universe explanation of physical principles.  Indeed, it explicitly states that we take them as read, exactly as the characters in the story do. It asks for the mass of a fictional object, given various things that we are outright told in the story.  Like how people ask about the size/mass/atmosphere/satellites of the Death Star, or the time dilation and gravitation in _Interstallar_, or the mass of the TARDIS; all of which are questions here.

Comment: "Let's assume general relativity as in the real universe" - You're asking for real-world out-of-universe physics to be used, so in fact you _are_ asking for an out-of-universe explanation. If you want it to be _in_-universe, you have to use _in_-universe physics.

Comment: @Valorum [The policy says](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7367/31394) "In-Universe Explanations -- **Even Based On Real Science** -- Are On-Topic". This question seems to be asking for an in-universe analysis of an in-universe object based on in-universe observations and real-science deductions. How is that off-topic?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Questions that are devoid of scifi content are off-topic. What he's asking is "*how big would a black hole need to be to achieve a specified amount of time dilation*". That's not a question we should be answering

Comment: @JdeBP You should be able to cast a reopen vote on your own question, which will put it into the Reopen Votes queue for community review.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Note that the OP is asking for the in-universe physics (anti-grav, magic thrust engines) to be disregarded

Comment: @Valorum No, he's asking "how big was this specific black hole in this on-topic story?" To answer that, you'd need to use information from the story, and potentially (given that DW is far from being hard sci-fi) discover contradictions therein, which would make for an interesting "we don't know" answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - "*Let's assume a thrust of 1G*". That's not what we see in the show. "*Let's assume general relativity*-  Why? "*Let's also assume common Terran sizes of skyscrapers*" - Why should we?

Comment: @Valorum I've forgotten too much of my physics to be sure what that means, but OP says it's "consistent with what appears on screen".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's not a bad question, just not one that's on-topic here.